# Solving for a nonlinear Hamiltonian using SciPy's fsolve

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am in the midst of solving for a nonlinear Hamiltonian of a dimer, which consists of 2 complex wavefunctions. I am using SciPy's root solver method by iterations. Thus, the complex input for my initial guess has to be encoded into real and imaginary parts, which will then make the initial 2x1 matrix equation into a 4x1 matrix equation.

What I've tried :

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
import numpy as np
import cmath
from math import pi

k = np.linspace(-pi, pi, 100)
v = 1
w = 1
H = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=complex)
H[0, 1] = v+w*cmath.exp(-1j*k)
H[1, 0] = v+w*cmath.exp(1j*k)
E=np.zeros((2,2), )
E[0,1]=-(v**2+w**2+2*v*w*math.cos(k))**0.5
E[1,0]=(v**2+w**2+2*v*w*math.cos(k))**0.5
  
def f(x):
    psi = np.zeros((2,1),float)
    psi[0]=np.isreal(x[0])+1j*np.iscomplex(x[1])
    psi[1]=np.isreal(x[2])+1j*np.iscomplex(x[3])
    f=(H-E)*psi
    return f
    
m = fsolve(f,np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]]))

print (m.x)
```

The error message that I'm getting is as follows

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars #for line 12
```

I need help to rectify this mistake.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ok, i have rectified it.